# Way to force fetch of POP3 email via google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, pop3

I'm using gmail as my web interface for an external email account and am fetching data via gmail's POP3 connection.  I'm also using it to send mail from that account, so the ability to reply from that address in gmail is key (hence not just forwarding the emails from the 3rd party account).

The issue is that the fetch frequency is automatically and dynamically set by Google based on email volumes - so if I don't get a bunch of emails, the polling slows down to hourly.  Wondering if there is a way to have an Apps Script that runs every 5 minutes or so and forces a POP3 refresh?

Comment: Can you share more details and documentation on what you are trying to do? Are you referring to this, [Synchronizing Clients with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync)?

Comment: Not the Gmail API, but within Gmail, you can use POP3 to check email from non google accounts [google support doc] (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). The question is how to use google app scripts (can you?) to increase the poll frequency for checking those external accounts as there is no user setting for it.

Comment: Do not include "I found nothing" as it doesn't help to make the question clearer, instead describe your search efforts. Include a brief description of the search keywords and about the most relevant questions / answers that you have read related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

[Daniel Slaughters GMail POP3 Checker](https://www.danielslaughter.com/project/gmailpop3/) will do just that for you. It is a script that runs in Tampermonkey on Chrome or Greasemonkey in Firefox.
You can set it to let GMail check the pop3-accounts every couple of minutes.
Close and restart the browser after installation to get it going.
It is 'donationware' - so you're free to give what it is worth to you, even just some dollars. The website claims the minimum check time is 12 minutes if you have not donated, but I think in reality it is more like 5 minutes or even less (I have donated, so I can't check that anymore).

Comment: affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Nope, no affiliation, just a happy user.  Btw - affiliation on freeware (what donationware essentially is) - really?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the documentation regarding POP3 under Apps Script and the Gmail API the only thing that seems available is to configure the POP settings at:

- [Method: users.settings.getPop](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/getPop)
- [Method: users.settings.updatePop](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/updatePop)

You can create a new Feature Request on Google Issue Tracker to ask for this feature, this is the template link for the Gmail API component:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107